# Priced app on Google play can't be bought

Tags: android, google-play, payment

I just made my first paid app for android and published it on google play.
I configured my wallet to be a merchant account, added my bank account to receive payments and everything else.

My app is already published, but I tried to buy it and it can't complete the process, Google play keeps saying "error getting the status of the transaction" (or something like this).

My credit card is ok, since I can buy every other app.

What can be wrong?

thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that I can't buy my own apps on Google play... Sorry.

I thought Google play worked the same way as apple's App Store, where I can buy my own apps.

I like to buy them like a normal customer for testing purposes and to make sure updates are being delivered correctly.